# Can i trigger a click event on a link with onclick=return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to trigger a click event even thow the return false?
The reason for the onClick return false is that the page is "jumping" with out it clicking on the link.

The link tag is looking like this:

```
<li class="tab"><a href="#" onClick="return false;" data-target="#home-tab">Home</a></li>
```

i have tried this with no luck:

```
$("a [data-taget='#home-tab']").live('click', function(){

    });
```

Comment: have you looked at .trigger(); ?

Comment: You want to click the link without going to anywhere from href??

Comment: `onClick="return false;"` remove this and use it within your click event.

Comment: I think you can put the `return false` at the end of the click event *instead* to get the same behavior but have the event triggered.

Comment: Worth noting that `live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9 in favor for `on()`. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I've identified the issues for you, have a look at the answer i've posted for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[data-target='#home-tab']").on('click', function(){
    alert(123);
});
```

with the HTML:

```
<li class="tab"><a href="#" onClick="return false;" data-target="#home-tab">Home</a></li>
```

This works fine. `.live()` is deprecated and you had some typing errors i fixed for you. http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/n7L2w15L/

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of  " `href='#'`" is, while clicking this attribute it will go to the top of of the page. To prevent this use "`event.preventDefault()`" function which will prevent the default behavior of the href.

Answer (score 0):

returning false is for having the ink not doing what it is supposed to do on click i.e: the link will redirect no longer, here i am assuming you want the script to do something with the link.
Frankly speaking, nobody really here understands what you are trying to achieve. Try asking more clearly, perhaps phrase yourself better :)

Answer (score 0):

Just target the link in a different way like the following example.

http://jsfiddle.net/j4k306e6/

html

```
<li class="tab"><a id="home-tab" onclick="return false;" href="#" data-target="#home-tab">Home</a></li>
```

javascript

```
$("a#home-tab").bind('click', function(){
    alert("");
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("a [data-taget='#home-tab']").live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //your code
});
```

and remove onClick="return false" from html

Comment: OP wants the return false